# Additional field on product page on WordPress (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

Welcome,

I've script in functions.php on my WP and would like to add an additional field to the product page. I can add additional info on edit product page but it doesn't show on the product page.

Can you help?

```
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');

// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields() {
global $woocommerce, $post;
echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
woocommerce_wp_text_input(
array(
'id' => '_custom_product_number_field',
'placeholder' => '',
'label' => __('Precio tarjeta ($)', 'woocommerce'),
'type' => 'number',
'custom_attributes' => array(
'step' => 'any',
'min' => '0'`enter code here`
)
)
);
echo '</div>';
}

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id) {
$woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['_custom_product_number_field'];
if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field))
update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));
}

function action() {
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_product_number_field', true);
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action', 15 );
```